# Master branch reflects older version

Tags: git, git-branch

I have three branches:

- `master`
- `version1`
- `version2`

`master` and `version1` are identical, is this normal? Or should `master` reflect the lastest version aka `version2`?

What do I do here?

Comment: It depends completely on your usage of Git. Generally though, it might be expected that master contains the latest copy of the production code. This blog post provides an example as to how a branching model might be applied in Git: http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model

Comment: You can use `gitk --all` to get an overview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use branch per feature and versions are just tags of potential release candidates or the ones that actually made it through to production. Those are usually on the master branch. Here is the write up I did on branch per feature. It touches on where you tag versions and when you merge to master: http://dymitruk.com/blog/2012/02/05/branch-per-feature/